# Is QuickSort really the fastet sorting technique

Tags: quicksort

Hello all this is my very first question here. I am new to datastructure and algorithms my teacher asked me to compare time complexity of different algorithms including: merge sort, heap sort, insertion sort, and quick sort. I search over internet and find out that quick sort is the fastest of all but my version of quick sort is the slowest of all (it sort 100 random integers in almost 1 second while my other sorting algorithms took almost 0 second). I tweak my quick sort logic many times (taking first value as pivot than tried to take middle value as pivot but in vain) I finally search the code over internet and there was not much difference in my code and code on internet. Now I really am confused that if this is behaviour of quick sort is natural (I mean whatever your logic is you are gonna get same results.) or there are some specific situations where you should use quick sort. In the end I know my question is not clear (I don't know how to ask besides my english is also not very good.) I hope someone can help me I really wanted to attach picture of awkward result I am having but I can't (reputation < 10).

Comment: What's your input? Where's your code?

Comment: Then your code is wrong. QS should be considerably faster than any of the other sorts you mentioned when sorting an array of 100 random integers, and if it isn't you've written a flawed implementation. (I can't tell you how it's flawed, because I can't see your code from here.) I have code that sorts 1000-10000 random integers using several different sorts for comparison, and QS is consistently the fastest algorithm of the five I've tested.

Comment: Are you sorting random numbers every time? If you aren't, it could be you're getting closer to a best case scenario with the other sorts.

Comment: Yes I am sorting random numbers every time @ Jeremy W.

Comment: Yes I was sorting random numbers every time @ Jeremy W. Yes my code WAS wrong as I replied Shawn Lee that unwanted recursive calls made the function to take more time but now it is solved thanks for rapid response.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, quicksort is supposed to be the fastest algorithm for sorting, with a runtime of O(nlogn). It's worst case would be O(n^2), but only occurs if there are repeated values are equal to the pivot. 
In your situation, I can only assume that your pivot value is not ideal in your data array, but is still able to sort the values using that pivot. Otherwise, your quicksort implementation is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: Yes my implementation was completely incorrect I dry run my code last night (I thought before posting my code I should dry run it again) and found that recursion part was a big mess function was recursively calling itself even if array is completely sorted. I managed recursive calls to be called only when needed and problem vanished. Thanks for your response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort has O(n^2) worst-case runtime and O(nlogn) average case runtime. A good reason why Quicksort is so fast in practice compared to most other O(nlogn) algorithms such as Heapsort, is because it is relatively cache-efficient. Its running time is actually O(n/Blog(n/B)), where B is the block size. Heapsort, on the other hand, doesn't have any such speedup: it's not at all accessing memory cache-efficiently.

The value you choose as pivot may not be appropriate hence your sorting may be taking some time.You can avoid quicksort’s worst-case run time of O(n^2) **almost** entirely by using an appropriate choice of the pivot – such as picking it at random.

Also , the best and worst case often are extremes **rarely occurring** in practice.But any average case analysis assume some distribution of inputs. For sorting, the typical choice is the random permutation model (as assumed on Wikipedia).

Comment: Other aspects of the `O(1)` constant is good for quicksort too; IIRC, in the typical case, it does almost half as many comparisons as heapsort would.